# Flutter: & JSON Why is the list treated as null even though it is not null. (The API i am fetching from does not have null values)

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I am making a simple weather app with flutter where I fetch the weather information from an API using the http package.
I am parsing the JSON into Dart classes so I can display it in another screen.

**This is the Weather forecast class**

```
class FivedayForecastData {
    String cod;
    int message;
    int cnt;
    List<ListElement> list;
    City city;

    FivedayForecastData({
        required this.cod,
        required this.message,
        required this.cnt,
        required this.list,
        required this.city,
    });

    factory FivedayForecastData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FivedayForecastData(
        cod: json["cod"],
        message: json["message"],
        cnt: json["cnt"],
        list: List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))),
        city: City.fromJson(json["city"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cod": cod,
        "message": message,
        "cnt": cnt,
        "list": List<dynamic>.from(list.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "city": city.toJson(),
    };
}
```

[It says that .map() was called on null even though this 'list' field is not null in the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pAUg.png)

**This is the function that fetches data from the API**

```
  required double lattitude,
  required double longitude,
}) async {
  final link =
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey&units=metric';

  final result = await http.get(Uri.parse(link));
  if (result.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = fivedayForecastDataFromJson(result.body.toString());
    // print(data);
    return data;
  }
}
```

[Part of the JSON data from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIYQJ.png)

I'm still learning and figuring out things about http and flutter in geenral
I tried making this list nullable just to get the app to run but it's always defaulting to the empty list
[It always defaults to the empty list []](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shWwM.png)

Comment: Can you also show your ListElement model?

Comment: Maybe your result variable is String, can you check its type

`print(result.runtimeType)`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this way

```
factory FivedayForecastData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FivedayForecastData(
    cod: json["cod"],
    message: json["message"],
    cnt: json["cnt"],
    list: json["list"] != null ? List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))) : [],
    city: City.fromJson(json["city"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "cod": cod,
    "message": message,
    "cnt": cnt,
    "list": list.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),
    "city": city.toJson(),
};
}
```